# Process exits unexpectedly with the return value of 3221225477

Tags: c++, dynamic-arrays

my program exits out of the blue with the return value of 3221225477. Below is the code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;
const int MAX_VALUE=-1;
int main(){
    int* numbers= NULL;
    int capacity=0;
    int size=0;
    while(true){
        int number;
        cout<<"Enter number: ";
        cin>> number;
        if(number==MAX_VALUE) break;
        if(size==capacity){
            numbers= new int[(sizeof(int)*(size+1))];
        }
        numbers[size]=number;
        size++;
        capacity++;
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        cout<< "You inputted: "+numbers[i];
    }
}
```

Here is the picture of the output:

https://pasteboard.co/Jn6SBBQ.png

(I tried uploading it via imgur from the built-in editor here but it was giving me an error of unable to reach imgur)

Comment: The `new []` operator allocates a number of *elements*, not an amount of bytes. Therefore you never need to multiply by the type size. There are also many other problems with the code you show, many (including the one I mentioned) will be solved if you use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: I was actually watching Harcard CS50 video and it was in C and I had to change the code to C++ (bc my professor wants the code in that). Could you please recommend the changes that I need to make in order to make this code work?

Comment: Just to be tidy, you probably should have a `delete [] numbers;` at the end too.

Comment: Oh, and you don't copy the old values when you grow the array. In fact, every value except the newly added one is uninitialized. And you leak the old array.

Comment: You're allocating `sizeof(int)` (which is probably four) times as much memory as you think. Don't try to learn C++ by translating C – they are very different languages and unless you know both languages really well, you're pretty much guaranteed to fail.

Comment: Few comments. 1) Don't call integer `-1` `MAX_VALUE`, the term is `sentinel`; 2) your `size is ALWAYS equal to `capacity` (they get incremented together), so the test `if(size==capacity)` is useless (always true); 3) you don't copy the previous content of the  `numbers` to the newly allocated array, and you don't initialize it either; 4) you leak all previously allocated arrays, need to `delete` them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this line:

```
cout << "You inputted: " + numbers[i];
                      // ^ incorrect
```

you are adding an `int` to a `char[15]`. If the `int` is greater than the size of the array, `cout` will try to print an array that lies at invalid memory, which invokes undefined behavior. This can cause the program to crash or return some error code.

Instead, you need to do:

```
cout<< "You inputted: " << numbers[i];
```

Comment: oh Thanks. looks like I was mixing up the syntax from other language. But, having made the changes you suggested, I'm not getting a different unexpected output. Here's the pic of that: https://pasteboard.co/Jn6WzW4.png

Comment: There's a number of issues with your code. The answer just addresses the UB. For starters, why are you using `new`? Are you aware of `std::vector`?

Comment: I haven't studied vectors yet

Comment: Then I strongly recommend learning that. It's a simple concept, and there's probably a related container in whichever programming language you're used to.

Comment: @Zain763 If this answer solves the question, the consider accepting it, so the question is resolved.